# Why i can't replace field in mongoose document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

`vk_account.settings` is an Array in mongoose schema.

```
vk_account.save(function(err, vk_account) {
    if(err) return cb(err, null);
    vk_account.Sources = updated_sources;
    vk_account.settings = account_setting;
    cb(null, vk_account);
})
```

I want to replace `vk_account.settings(Array)` to one certain object from the `vk_account.settings`, which is `account_setting(Object)`, but when I replace it, it does not get replaced and `vk_account.settings` as before has old value.

As I understand it, the mongoose prohibits and does not assign an Object to a variable of type Array, but I don't want to save it, I just want to send it to the client and forget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you cannot assign same value for save as well as for response `vk_account`... Then you have to change the `instance` to `object` using `toObject()` and then you can add keys in it

```
       vk_account.save(function(err, vk) {
          if(err) return cb(err, null);
          var object = vk.toObject();
          vk.Sources = updated_sources;
          vk.settings = account_setting;
          cb(null, vk);
        })
```